# Setting font-family via style.font doesn't work unless font size is also set

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I want to set the font of a bit of text through some JavaScript.  For some reason, it seems that I can only do so when setting the `font-size` as well.  So this works:

```
el.style.font = "10px arial, serif"
```

but this doesn't

```
el.style.font = "arial, serif"
```

([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LkyxF/2/))

I know there are other ways to set the font, but for other reasons this approach would be convenient --  why isn't it working?

I've checked both Firefox and Chrome, so I assume it's something I don't understand as opposed to a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because according to [the definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-prop) from W3C, `font-size` must be there if you include `font-family`.

```
[
    [ <‘font-style’> || <font-variant-css21> || <‘font-weight’> || <‘font-stretch’> ]?
    <'font-size'>
    [ / <'line-height'> ]?
    <'font-family'>
]             | 
caption       |
icon          |
menu          |
message-box   |
small-caption |
status-bar
```

Edit: Updated to CSS3 definition.

Comment: All part of the charm of SO. :p

Comment: I don't remember it being quite so bad as this when I've used SO before.  :)  (I also had about 7 people reply with missing-the-point answers only to delete them once downvoted.)  This is the correct answer, of course.

Comment: When they don’t bother deleting them is when you’ll know it’s gotten worse. :p

Comment: I haven’t this rapidly… but watch this!

Answer (score 1):

You’re mistaking [`font`](http://w3.org/tr/css21/fonts.html#propdef-font) for [`font-family`](http://w3.org/tr/css21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) (`fontFamily` in JS-speak).

Comment: To be exact: the size in the shorthand font specification is not optional.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I certainly wasn't confusing the two, but I didn't realize that size was not optional.  Could you put that as an answer @UlrichSchwarz?